# Angular 2+ 4+ connecting an outside api with angular headers

Tags: angular, rest, web-services, http-headers

I needs some help connecting an outside ServiceNow API with an Angular Request header. Not sure if I am doing this the proper way or not. Thanks for any help.

```
url = 'https://dev21120.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_query=active%3Dtrue%5Eshort_descriptionLIKEemail&sysparm_display_value=true&sysparm_fields=number%2Cshort_description&sysparm_limit=10'

Headers
Accept application/json
Content-Type application/json
X-UserToken44ca4971db0313002bf5d001cf9619f880b26a74bf9250a48d9e765a49757f28d8b26cd7
```

I keep getting authorization error and I am thinking its the way I am passing in my headers

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic' + btoa(this.username + ':' + this.password)); 
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
}

getStuff() {
  this.http.get(this.url)
  return this.http.get(this.url)
  .map(response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: I believe it needs a space after the word `Basic`. There's also no need to add the `Content-Type` header, as Angular will handle this for you.

Comment: consider using the 'new' http client... the old one is already deprecated in v4

Comment: also, headers.append() does not mutate the headers object, it returns a new one with the new header added.